# cannot add or update a child row error with temp table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i keep getting the 'cannot add or update a child row' error and i cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong or how to fix the issue. the id field within all three tables have been set to unique and auto increment, so my thought was that if the 'slect * from(...)tbltmp' returns no value, than it would auto assign a new value upon insertion of the data.

```
INSERT INTO schedule (id, employee_id, project_id, project_phase, year_week, hours)
VALUES(
    (SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT schedule.id 
        FROM schedule 
        JOIN employees on employees.id = schedule.employee_id 
        WHERE employees.Employee=? 
        AND schedule.project_phase=? 
        AND schedule.year_week=?)
    tbltmp),
    (SELECT id 
    FROM employees 
    WHERE Employee=?),
    (SELECT MIN(pID) 
    FROM projects 
    WHERE pNUM = ? 
    AND pPhase = ?),
    ?,
    ?,
    ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hours=?'
```

this is what the error says

```
'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectscheduler`.`schedule`, CONSTRAINT `employee_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'
```

any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for to update or add a row in a children table but the foreign key of children table was not found into the parent table.

Check the foreign keys in the parent table.